# How a solar charge controller can work on both 12 volt and 24 volt

Tags: voltage, basic

Please excuse me for my silly question, I have basic understanding of electrical circuits.

I came across a solar charge controller which was rated for both 12 v and 24 v. My understanding is that charge controllers work by cutting off beyond a particular voltage (like beyond 14.4 volt for 12 volt charge controller). So how can such a charge controller "figure" out the attached battery system voltage?

If the answer requires a diagram, I'll be happy to look into that, I can understand basic electric circuits (involving diode, cap, resistor, etc)

Comment: Can we see the specification for this controller?

Comment: http://www.snapdeal.com/product/sukam-solar-charge-controller-122448volt45/686023277544?utm_source=earth_feed&utm_campaign=9_570&utm_medium=109007849&vendorCode=S1b227

Comment: I get the distinct impression that there will be a selector switch on the back.

Answer (score 1):

If it has a microcontroller, you can have it detect what the voltage is and if it's within specific ranges 11-14V for example, have it do something. If it's within a different range, 18-28V for example, do something else.